# Stop someone Publishing a thesis without giving credits to original author

Tags: authorship, collaboration, conflict-of-interest

I am serving notice period and have written a thesis, matured enough to be published. All the work related to thesis has been done solely by me while I was working there before resignation. Now I am almost sure that my Manager will publish it without giving any due credits to me. How can this be tackled without confronting them?

Answer (score 2):

You can't reasonably stop someone else from *trying* to publish something.

You could however file your thesis right now (at ArXiV or a similar venue) to establish a time stamp. If then later your thesis is published under another name, you could ask the journal for a retraction. Be prepared to prove that you are not the one trying to get credit for your manager's work, though.

If you do not want to expose your current version of your thesis (and you do not want to demonstrate a lack of trust by publishing an unfinished version of your thesis), you could make a PDF that includes your name and publish its *hash value* in a way that it gets timestamped (there may be other services for this). This allows you to prove later that you had this PDF already at the said time of publishing the hash value.

Note that using your text verbatim without your permission is probably a violation of copyright. Again, you need to make sure that you can later prove that you are the author and you have the text already today to make legal actions possible.

I'm not touching on the topic of whether your suspicion is reasonable in this answer.

Comment: It sounds as though aryahatta may be working for a company. In this case it's possible that the copyright in their work lies with the company, not them.

Comment: @Flyto Thanks for pointing that out. That would be quite indeed quite a bad situation: in this case, the OP could not publish without violating copyright (unless some higher up in the company agrees), and anyone else could not publish without violating academic integrity.

Comment: @DCTLib Thanks for your inputs. I will not be able to publish seperately as per the company policy, that is correct. But concern is how the company people can be detered from publishing without highlighting my efforts. I would explore how to get the timestamp with using hashvalue. If you can help me on this ( i.e. fullproof the ownership ) I will be grateful.

Comment: @aryabhatta I only know the classical approach to establish a time stamp. Make a SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512 hash of your PDF using some program (e.g., sha256 <filename> will do on Linux) and then order a small newspaper ad/insert that is archived super-regionally and just post the hash value there. Depending on your jurisdiction, you could also pay a notary to time-stamp a sheet of paper with the hash value. Note that only the technically knowledgable people will accept a proof that a hash value was known at a point in time as a proof of existance of the document during at the time stamped.

Comment: @aryabhatta Other approaches to time-stamping may exist and are definitely in use for certain financial stuff, but I am not an expert on them.